# Get realtime output from a long-running executable using python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, logging, subprocess

It's my first time asking a question on here so bear with me.

I'm trying to make a python3 program that runs executable files for x amount of time and creates a log of all output in a text file. For some reason the code I have so far works only with some executables. I'm new to python and especially subprocess so any help is appreciated.

```
import time
import subprocess 

def CreateLog(executable, timeout=5):
   
    time_start = time.time()
    process = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, text=True)

    f = open("log.txt", "w")

    while process.poll() is None:
        output = process.stdout.readline()

        if output:
            f.write(output)
        if time.time() > time_start + timeout:
            process.kill()
            break
```

I was recently experimenting with crypto mining and came across nanominer, I tried using this python code on nanominer and the log file was empty. I am aware that nanominer already logs its output, but the point is why does the python code fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are interacting through `.poll()` (R U dead yet?) and `.readline()`.
It's not clear you want to do that.

There seems to be two cases for your long-lived child:

- it runs "too long" silently
- it runs forever, regularly producing output text at e.g. one-second intervals

The 2nd case is the easy one.
Just use `for line in process.stdout:`, consume the line,
peek at the clock, and maybe send a `.kill()` just as you're already doing.
No need for `.poll()`, as child exiting will produce EOF on that pipe.

For the 1st case, you will want to set an alarm.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#example

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)
```

After "too long", five seconds, your handler will run.
It can do anything you desire.
You'll want it to have access to the `process` handle,
which will let you send a `.kill()`.